# Why don't the collisions of the particles in a gas affect its temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, kinetic-theory

Temperature is defined as the mean kinetic energy of the system. Now the particles are constantly colliding with each other; as a result of which kinetic energy of each particle changes.

> **Definition of Thermal Equilibrium** :  When each and every part of the system has the same temperature i.e. no net heat flow, then the system is in thermal equilibrium.

If it is so, then how can there be the same temperature as each and every particle is undergoing change in its kinetic energy? And what is *mean kinetic energy*?

There must inevitably be deviations from the mean kinetic energy due to collisions.
But then how can the temperature be the same at each point of the system?

Comment: Temperature is not actually defined as the mean kinetic energy, but, that aside, what precisely is your confusion? *Mean* kinetic energy intrinsically means that the "true" kinetic energy fluctuates about the mean value in time. That's what a mean *is* - an average over a certain time frame, which, for systems in thermal equilibrium, is by definition itself constant.

Comment: Question is not so bad.It doesnt deserve downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

> how can then there be same temperature at each & every point of the system?

Temperature is a bulk property of a system.  Once a system has reached thermal equilibrium, it will not be the case that each object in the system has the same KE.  Instead, there is a well-defined [distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) of energies for the objects in the system.

For everyday objects, when we talk about the temperature at a point, there are still millions of atoms or molecules interacting.  So the concept of an average KE is valid.  We do not single out one (or five) and attempt to calculate a separate temperature for them.

Answer (score 1):

> And what is mean kinetic energy???

In [statistical mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_mechanics) Temperature is [identified as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature#Kinetic_theory_of_gases)

[image: kinetic temperature]

for gases , so it is called the average kinetic energy identified by the root mean square of the velocity.

> There must be inevitably deviation from their mean kinetic energy due to collisions; how can then there be same temperature at each & every point of the system? Plz help.

The kinetic energy is a distribution and will be continually changing in a gas by collisions. The reason one can do thermodynamics with statistical mechanics is because of the large value of the [Avogadro  number](http://%206.02214129(27)%C3%971023%20mol%E2%88%921) ,  $6.02214129(27) \times10^{23}~\text{mol}^{−1}$ . This allows to treat any volume of air as continuous , the size of atoms is so small and becomes irrelevant except in average effects.

Answer (score -4):

actually, if you would consider a whole system  ..then its KE would not be transfered to anywhere or changed, therefore the overall temperature of system would be the same

and if you would consider individual molecule   ..then yess   there would be a variotion in temperature

Comment: An individual molecule doesn't really *have* a temperature - temperature is a property of thermodynamic systems in equilibrium, not of their smallest parts.

Comment: +1@ACuriousMind; Sir, how much deviation from the mean KE  wouldn't actually bother the temperature??